# Google Maps API no longer shows routes or markers

Tags: qt, google-maps-api-3

I am using a QWebView to show a Google Maps API. Through the UI, the user puts in some addresses and these places will be shown as markers on the map.

With a traveling salesman algorithm, the program will calculate the shortest route and fabricate an HTML that will show this shortest route using Google Maps. This HTML will be shown through the the QWebView.

This is all been working nicely, but since last week the same code (my code hasn't changed) stopped working on Windows machines but keeps functioning on my Linux boxes.

The HTML code is working perfectly in any other webbrowser.

I find it absolutely weird that the QWebView stopped showing the route / markers since that date, and only on Windows computers, the code runs perfectly on Linux.

What did I miss? Which test could I run to find a solution?

It seems to me that something has changed in the Google Maps API that is now disturbing the communications between the Windows version of the QWebView and the HTML code.

Did something change in the Google Maps API around the 22nd of November 2017 ?

(project: https://github.com/vvim/routetool - issue https://github.com/vvim/routetool/issues/49 )

Comment: yep, new version 3.31 was released on 21st of November 2017: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test the maps link with older version. I had the same issue and I've solved it using `v=3.29`

The link will be:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Dear @Alaa Agwa, you are my hero :-) Thank you very much, this solved my problem!

Comment: Welcome @Wim :-)

Comment: This solution no longer works. Google has retired version 3.29